# get current logged in user data from firebase along with profile picture

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a registered user in firebase and want to get the current logged in user profile data along with his profile picture.
I'm able to get its name, number and other details but I'm not able to get profile picture which I have stored in firebase storage.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that Firebase can read a `Uri.class` from the database. More likely you'll want to:

1. Read the value from the database as a string.
2. Convert that to a URI in your code.

So:

```
String url = snapshot.child("profilePicture").getValue(String.class);
Uri myimageValue = Uri.parse(url);
```

Comment: it is giving me an error that URi is an abstract and cant be instantiated